# Setting up TortoiseSVN server on Windows 7

Tags: tortoisesvn

I need to set up tortoise svn on a share that is hosted on our server. I read this is not wise, but I dont mind, because only me and my manager uses that. Anyone done that before? Would appreciate any help.

Comment: What "help" do you need? Do you have an actual question? As per the [FAQ], this is a Q&A site. It's not set up to provide general advice.

Answer (score 2):

TortoiseSVN is not a server and includes no server components.

Anytime you are using  a repository on a network and/or sharing with another user, you need to be running a server (svnserve or Apache). Ignoring best practices & other advice with "I know it's wrong, but I don't mind, it's only two of us" is faulty and you *will* eventually have a problem.